# Javascript loops are crashing my website

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a question about Javascript and HTML. Below I have my code, and I'm not sure why but whenever I try and run it(ie: hit Submit), my website freezes. I have it set right now so that it checks if the username/password EXISTS, but it does not have to be a combination of the 2 quite yet. Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title> Welcome to my website!</title>
    <body>
        <form action="action_page.php" method = "post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="user">
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myLogin()">    
         </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myLogin(){
            var usernames = ["rdoucett", "hovland"];
            var passwords = ["Rd200161", "hovland1"];
            usernames[5] = "stop";
            passwords[5] = "stop";
            var a = false;
            var b = false;
      var i = 1;
    while(a===false) {
        if(usernames[i] != form.user.value) {
            i++;
        }else if(usernames[i] == form.user.value){
            a=true;
        }else if(usernames[i] == "stop"){
            alert("Incorrect username or password!");
            a=true;
        };
    };
    i  = 1;
    while(b===false) {
        if(passwords[i] != form.pass.value) {
            i++;
        }else if(passwords[i] == form.pass.value){
            b=true;
        }else if(passwords[i] == "stop"){
            alert("Incorrect username or password!");
            b=true;
        };
    };
    if(b&&a===true){
    alert("Welcome " + document.getElementsByName("user") + "!");
    }else{
    alert("I do not recognize you " + document.getElementsByName("pass") + "!");
    };
};
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: replace if(b&&a==true) with if(b==true&&  a==true)

Comment: Have you tried putting in a break point and stepping through the code?

Comment: This seems like a horribly long and inefficient way of doing things. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: is that seriously a login validation?

Comment: However it is a legit question tho with valid question content and code, that it is inefficient is the least of the concerns since people can just read the script to find the login anyways. I also *think* (s)he is a beginner with JS atleast, +1 to you for the link into the right direction tho! @j08691

Comment: @Diego do note not all people are code-librarians from the start or did you write epic code right from the start with full understanding? ^.^

Comment: Disregarding all the (rightly) critiques, you'll never reach the `else if(usernames[i] == "stop"){` block, because either the first condition is true, or the second condition is true.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, no, of course not and I didn't mean to offend him/her, I wanted to know if this was really the login code or some code adapted for us to help him/her

Comment: @Diego in that case I said nothing! - sometimes the context gets misplaced in a comment that looks serious :)

Comment: Do not validate logins with javascript. It is very very insecure since anyone can see it. Also you should detect onclick events in javascript.

Comment: While loops in the past were used in login forms to stop execution of the page and allow for an unfettered redirect without further processing on the page. This is not weird code, just an old approach. It's locking because the conditionals a, and b are never false and the loops are executing 100% of the cpu time allocated to the thread (thus the ability to lock out execution and a condition which appears to be a crash).

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a while loop at all, just exit the myLogin function if it was an invalid username or password.

Be aware that what you have written here is completely insecure. Anyone visiting your website with even a basic technical knowledge can see your full list of usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code a lot, but I think it is what you wanted. In your scenario beside a few errors, any valid username and any valid password would match. (i.e. `user = "rdoucett"` and `psw= "hovland1"`).

```
function myLogin(){
    var usernames = ["rdoucett", "hovland"];
    var passwords = ["Rd200161", "hovland1"];
    var username;
    for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
        if (usernames[i] == form.user.value) {
            username = usernames[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!username || passwords[i] != form.pass.value) {
        alert("Incorrect username or password!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Welcome " + document.getElementsByName("user") + "!");
    }
};
```

From the security point of view, as already been said this is very insecure. You should think the `HTML` and `JS` as information any client can see. So this kind of functionality is what you **must do** server side.

Also note that the alerts wont avoid the form of being submitted. If you want to avoid that, you should add `return false;`.